# how can i use webview keypress event?

Tags: android

i want to use webview keypress event with imagebutton fuction

when i click imagebutton, i want to press keyboard key "W" Or "S"

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)
    webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com")
    val webSettings = webView.settings
    webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true


    val imageButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton)
    imageButton?.setOnClickListener {

        webView.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_W)

    }


}
```